# Element-wise apply array of functions to array of values in numpy, efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with functions and another one with values:

```
f = np.array([np.sin,np.cos,lambda x: x**2])
x = np.array([0,0,3])
```

I want to apply each function to each element in `x`. This can be easily done as

```
np.array([F(X) for F,X in zip(f,x)])
```

Is there a more efficient way that does not involve a `for` loop? Something like just `f(x)` (which of course does not works).

Comment: Do you want to avoid *writing* a ``for`` loop, or do you want to avoid *executing* a ``for`` loop (say, via vectorisation)?

Comment: Avoid executing the `for` loop and replace it for some more efficient vectorized way.

Comment: Since you are applying the functions to scalar values, using `list` and `math` functions instead of `numpy` will be faster.  List iterate faster, and `math.sin(1)` is faster than `np.sin(1)`.

Comment: Your `f` array is `object` dtype.  The fast, no-loop, compiled methods work with numeric dtypes.  `object` dtype is effectively a list - the elements are references to objects.  The vaunted `numpy` "vectorization" means applying compiled methods to the arrays, moving the loops to compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
>>> def apply(func, arg):
        return func(arg)

>>> vectorized_apply = np.vectorize(apply)
>>> vectorized_apply(f, x)
array([0., 1., 9.])
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html): "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.". I guess there is no efficient way of doing what I want.

Comment: It should be mentioned, for loop is not always inefficient. Depending on the number of entries you have, for loop can sometimes prove to be more efficient that np operations. This answer just saves you writing an explicit for loop, nothing more.

Comment: Since `f` is object dtype, you should get a bit better speed with `np.frompyfunc`.  That's more competitive with the plain list comprehension in speed.